# Error: A value of type 'String' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to implement different languages (english & spanish) in my app, this is what I was thinking:

```
String selectedLanguage = 'en';

const Map<String, Map<String, String>> languageLabels = {
  'en': {
    'label1': 'label in English',
  },
  'es': {
    'label1': 'label in Spanish',
  },
};
```

And I was planning to use it as:

```
static String label1 = languageLabels[selectedLanguage['label1']];
```

But I keep getting this error

> Error: A value of type 'String' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'int'.

> static String label1 = languageLabels[selectedLanguage['label1']];
> ___________________________________________________________^

I read that it was because of null safety, but I just don't know how to solve it.

Comment: selectedLanguage is not map, so this usage is not correct: selectedLanguage['label1']. Also, languageLabels[..] will return Map<String,String> not String. You can update these usages and fix null safety issues later on by making Map<String,String>? for example. I hope, it helps!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try assigning it this way

```dart
String? label1 = languageLabels[selectedLanguage]?['label1'];
```

OR

```dart
String label1 = languageLabels[selectedLanguage]?['label1'] ?? '';
```

OR (I do not suggest it) if you are sure you will never get `null` value:

```dart
String label1 = languageLabels[selectedLanguage]!['label1']!;
```